# How does one start a thread in Clojure?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure

I've read a lot about how great Clojure is when it comes to concurrency, but none of the tutorials I've read actually explain how to create a thread. Do you just do (.start (Thread. func)), or is there another way that I've missed?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Clojure `fn`s are `Runnable` so it's common to use them in exactly the way you posted, yes.

```
user=> (dotimes [i 10] (.start (Thread. (fn [] (println i)))))
0                                                             
1                                                             
2                                                             
4                                                             
5                                                             
3                                                             
6                                                             
7                                                             
8                                                             
9                                                             
nil
```

Another option is to use [agents](http://clojure.org/agents), in which case you would `send` or `send-off` and it'll use a Thread from a pool.

```
user=> (def a (agent 0))
#'user/a
user=> (dotimes [_ 10] (send a inc))
nil
;; ...later...
user=> @a
10
```

Yet another option would be `pcalls` and `pmap`.  There's also `future`.  They are all documented in the [Clojure API](http://clojure.org/api).

Comment: Ah, yes, the agent mechanism was something I ha forgotten about. Thanks!

Comment: Dont forget the likes of pmap!

Comment: "Clojure fns are Runnable so it's common to use them in exactly the way you posted, yes." Thank you so very much for this information.

Comment: Minor correction: `send` will use a thread from a pool. `send-off` will use a solo thread. That is what differs between them. Use `send-off` if your action blocks (otherwise you risk blocking all the threads in the agent pool).

Answer (score 40):

Usually when I want to start a thread in Clojure I just use [future](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/future).

As well as being simple to use, this has the advantage that you avoid having to do any messy Java interop to access the underlying Java threading mechanisms.

**Example usage:**

```
(future (some-long-running-function))
```

This will execute the function asynchronously in another thread.

```
(def a (future (* 10 10)))
```

If you want to get the result, just dereference the future, e.g:

```
@a
=> 100
```

Note that @a will block until the future thread has completed its work.

Comment: Also note that exceptions are not thrown until you deref the future. see   https://stuartsierra.com/2015/05/27/clojure-uncaught-exceptions

Answer (score 14):

*Programming Clojure* doesn't address that question until page 167: "Use Agents for Asynchronous Updates".

Before you go starting threads, please note that Clojure will multitask on its own, given half a chance. I've written programs blithely ignorant of concurrency and found that when conditions are right, they occupy more than one CPU. I know that's not a very rigorous definition: I haven't explored this in depth yet.

But for those occasions when you really do need an explicit separate activity, one of Clojure's answers is apparently the agent.

`(agent initial-state)`

will create one. It's not like a Java Thread in terms of being a code block waiting to be executed. Instead, it's an activity waiting to be given work to do. You do this via

`(send agent update-fn & args)`

The example does

`(def counter (agent 0))`

`counter` is your name and handle for the agent; the agent's state is the number 0.

Having set that up, you can send work to the agent:

`(send counter inc)`

will tell it to apply the given function to its state.

You can later pull the state out of the agent by dereferencing it:

`@counter` will give you the current value of the number that started out at 0.

Function `await` will let you do something like a `join` on the agent's activity, should it be a long one:

`(await & agents)` will wait until they're all done; there's also another version that takes a timeout.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the way that you start a Java Thread in Clojure is something like what you have there.

However, the *real* question is: why would you want to do that? Clojure has *much* better concurrency constructs than threads.

If you look at the canonical concurrency example in Clojure, [Rich Hickey's ant colony simulation](https://github.com/juliangamble/clojure-ants-simulation/blob/master/src/ants.clj), you will see that is uses exactly 0 threads. The only reference to `java.lang.Thread` in the entire source is three calls to `Thread.sleep`, whose sole purpose is to slow the simulation down so that you can actually *see* what is going on in the UI.

All the logic is done in Agents: one agent for every ant, one agent for the animation and one agent for the pheromone evaporation. The playing field is a transactional ref. Not a thread nor lock in sight.

Comment: This is not correct. Clojure uses of course threads under the hood. But it provides abstractions to syncronise and coordinate these threads, eg. futures, pmap or agents. And then there are problems, where you want to use threads with the java.util.concurrent machinery.

Comment: I'd give Jörg the benefit of the doubt that when he says threads he means the Thread API, but that should be made clear.

Comment: What Clojure uses in its internal runtime to implement agents, futures and whatnot is Rich Hickey's business, not mine. The fact that today the JVM version of Clojure happens to use Thread pools is completely irrelevant to the language semantics. Tomorrow Rich might change his mind and implement them as Continuations, the .NET version of Clojure might implement them as `Task`s, ClojureScript (the JavaScript version of Clojure) might implement them as HTML5 Web Workers, and a hypothetical future Erlang-hosted version might implement them as Actors. As a Clojure user, I'll never know.

Comment: Not true. `pmap` will underperform `map` if the task is small enough. Abstractions are leaky, and you should always understand what is happening underneath.

Comment: Clojure is often leaky on purpose.  It exposes Java so you can take advantage of it.  (Clojure strings == Java strings etc.)  Clojure isn't going to break compatibility with plain Java Threads any time soon, would be my guess.

Comment: @Mike the pmap abstraction is not leaky ..noone ever stated that pmap will out perform map every single time.

Comment: @Surya Depends on your definition of leaky :) The fact that performing actions in parallel would be slower than actions performed in sequence seems impossible in an idealized (ie. perfectly abstracted) world. Proper application of `pmap` requires that you understand the cost of spawning and coordinating threads, so right there you've escaped the world of "ideal parallel application". That's what I mean by leaky; it wasn't meant as a criticism of the language. As Brian mentioned, it can often be a desirable aspect.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add my two cents (7 years later): Clojure functions implement the `IFn` [interface](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html) that extends `Callable` as well as `Runnable`. Hence, you can simply pass them to classes like `Thread`.

If your project might already uses [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async), I prefer using the `go` macro:

```clj
(go func)
```

This executes `func` in a super lightweight [IOC (inversion of control) thread](http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html):

> **go** [...] will turn the body into a state machine. Upon reaching any blocking operation, the state machine will be 'parked' and the actual thread of control will be released. [...] When the blocking operation completes, the code will be resumed [...]

In case `func` is going to do I/O or some long running task, you should use `thread` which is also part of core.async (check out [this](https://stuartsierra.com/2013/12/08/parallel-processing-with-core-async) excellent blog post):

```clj
(thread func)
```

Anyway, if you want to stick to the Java interop syntax, consider using the `->` (thread/arrow) macro:

```clj
(-> (Thread. func) .start)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a future is usually the simplest adhoc access to threading. Depends entirely on what you want to do :)

Answer (score 1):

The `(future f)` macro wraps the form f in a Callable (via fn*) and submits that to a thread pool immediately.

if you need a reference to a java.lang.Thread object, for instance, to use it as a java.lang.Runtime shutdown hook, you can create a Thread like this:

```
(proxy [Thread] [] (run [] (println "running")))
```

This will not start the thread yet, only create it. 
To create and run the thread, submit it to a thread pool or call .start on it:

```
(->
 (proxy [Thread] [] (run [] (println "running")))
 (.start))
```

Brians's answer also creates a thread but doesn't need proxy, so that's very elegant. On the other hand, by using proxy we can avoid creating a Callable.