# Idiomatic way to execute a task in (clojure's internal) thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, clojure, parallel-processing

I have tasks which I need to have execute on the background. They do not produce an interesting value, their side effects is their raison d'etre. These effects will be observed elsewhere later.

I could not find any function / macro in clojure that just takes a function and executes it in a background thread. future may be a match but I'm a little unsure as I'll never be dereferencing it. That in and of itself is not a problem but I am a little concerned whether there is a possibility that a future will be cancelled if the future object is garbage collected and the future has not yet started executing?

I'm doing something like this:

```
(doseq [task-fn task-fns]
  (future (task-fn))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure functions implement Runnable so you can turn them into threads which will complete in the background. See this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768706/827617

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with using `future` to spin off threads for side effects. It really doesn't matter whether or not you want to deref the result or not. And no, a `future` thread won't be cancelled due to gargabe collection.

As another user mentioned, you can absolutely use Java's thread execution mechanisms directly. Which you choose is really just a matter of style. I tend to use `future` personally.

If you happen to be using `core.async`, usage of `thread` or `go` is considered more appropriate (for I *think* a combination of practical and stylistic reasons, since it returns a channel). But I'm guessing that's not your case here.